# Disable Twitter Bootstrap collapse toggling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I'm using Twitter Boostraps component collapse to reveal some fields which is done by clicking in another field. However, if I click the same field again the other fields get hidden again (i.e toggling).

What I want is to disable the toggling so that the fields won't hide when clicking the field a second time. Could this be done easily with some built-in methods or do I need to dive deep into the js file to change it myself?

Comment: Did you find a more satisfactory answer than the one below?

Comment: @Reddog: Actually no. Still using the one below even though it's very hacky :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something as simple as..

```
$('#myDiv').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  preventDefault(e);
})
```

This handles the Bootstrap 3 `hide.bs.collapse` event, and prevents the DIV from being hidden again.

Demo: http://bootply.com/75650

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the reason that this is working is that preventDefault gets undefined (should be e.preventDefault(), not preventDefault(e)). This means you can write anything that's not a valid method inside the function and the script will stop working.

Comment: Is there a way to re-enable the Collapse after disabling it?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is actually pretty simple and the one marked as correct comes pretty close, here is how you can disable the toggle mechanism:

```
$('#myDiv').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  return isMyDivEnabled(); // true or false
}).on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  return isMyDivEnabled(); // true or false
});
```

Cheers

Chris

Comment: oops, the functions would have to be named isMyDivEnabled()